# Nao é possivel anexar devido ao erro de e/s via e-mail

Tags: android

Estou terminando de desenvolver um formulário no android studio, onde o usuário enviar uma imagem junto com informações via e-mail. Ja consegui fazer tudo, o problema agora é quando tiro a foto e vou enviar para o e-mail me aparece uma mensagem:

> nao é possivel anexar devido ao erro de e/s

conforme você pode ver abaixo: 
[image: erro]

Aqui minha classe onde desenvolvi meu formulário.

```
package br.com.diego.tecnologiadanet.fragments;



Spinner option;
Button btnSend;
EditText Nome;
EditText Message;
EditText Endereco;
EditText Telefone;
EditText Email;
ImageView img;
private Bitmap bitmap;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reclame, container, false);

    img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            abrirCamera();
        }
    });

    Nome = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nome1);
    Message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.msg);
    Endereco = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.endereco);
    Telefone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.telefone);
    Email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnSend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send);
    option = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    option.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.option, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    option.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String nome = Nome.getText().toString();
            String message = Message.getText().toString();
            String matricula = Endereco.getText().toString();
            String telefone = Telefone.getText().toString();
            String assunto = option.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String ema = Email.getText().toString();
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"marcos@wfprojetos.com.br"});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, assunto);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Nome: " +nome +'\n'+  "Endereço: "+matricula + '\n'+ "Telefone: "+telefone + '\n'+ "E-mail: "+ema + '\n'+ '\n'+message);
            email.setType("image/jpeg");
            File bitmapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/image.jpg");
            Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(bitmapFile);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);

            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Selecione o serviço de e-mail:"));
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView mtext = (TextView) view;
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Você selecionou: "+mtext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

public void abrirCamera(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    InputStream stream = null;

    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        try {
            if(bitmap != null){
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            stream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
           // bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            //img.setImageBitmap(resizeImage(getActivity(), bitmap, 700, 600));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (stream != null)
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}



private static Bitmap resizeImage (Context context, Bitmap bpmOriginal, float newWidth, float newHeight){
    Bitmap novoBpm = null;
    int w = bpmOriginal.getWidth();
    int h = bpmOriginal.getHeight();
    float densityFactor = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float novoW = newWidth * densityFactor;
    float novoH = newHeight * densityFactor;

    float scalaW = novoW /w;
    float scalaH = novoH /h;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scalaW, scalaH);
    novoBpm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bpmOriginal, 0, 0, w, h, matrix, true);
    return novoBpm;
}
```

Dei uma pesquisada e alguns comentários falam que não estou conseguindo pegar o endereço onde minha foto foi salva, será que meu código não está fazendo isso?

Comment: Como está seu `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: esta assim:    `<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    </application>

</manifest>`

Comment: Tente adicionar mais esta permissão de escrita em ralação ao método `getExternalStorageDirectory()` `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Adicionei a permissão mas continua com o mesmo problema =[.. falta so isso pra terminar meu apk.

Comment: Vejo ali no seu código também que você usa duas vezes o método `setType` na mesma referência da `Intent email`? Tenta comentar a segunda ali!

Comment: Comentei e a unica coisa que mudou foi que apareceu mais opçoes de compartilhamento, como dropbox, facebook.. e etc mas o problema continua =\ Igor aqui nao tem a opçao de chat? seria mais agil

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40469/discussion-between-carlos-diego-and-igor-mello).